# GET particular value from split string result in sql

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I FIRE BELOVED QUERY

```
SELECT value
FROM STRING_SPLIT('3G-4RPE-L250-S80-27K-UNV-DIM-WT-RG1-CP-S(9)', '-')
```

I GOT FOLLOWING RESULT

```
VALUE
3G
4RPE
L250
S80
27K
UNV
DIM
WT
RG1
CP
S(9)
```

IS IT POSSIBLE TO GET PARTICULAR WORD LIKE 4RPE, RG1 FROM ABOVE RESULT SET IN SQL?

Comment: Are you looking for N positions?

Comment: Sure. `Select * from (your query)z where value in ('4RPE','RG1')`

Comment: MySQL or sql-server?

Comment: Please Check your caps lock key

Comment: Yes John I am looking for N positions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is with a bit of JSON.   Here we convert your string into a JSON Array.  Then it becomes a small matter to extract the values.

**Example**

```
Declare @S varchar(max) =  '3G-4RPE-L250-S80-27K-UNV-DIM-WT-RG1-CP-S(9)'
Set @S = '["'+replace(string_escape(@S,'json'),'-','","')+'"]'

Select Pos1 = JSON_VALUE(@S,'$[1]')
      ,Pos8 = JSON_VALUE(@S,'$[8]')
```

**Results**

```
Pos1    Pos8
4RPE    RG1
```

**2nd Option**

```
Select *
 From  OpenJSON(@S)
 Where [key] in (1,8)
```

**Results**

```
key value   type
1   4RPE    1
8   RG1     1
```